# Inject partial View to div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a situation where I want dynamically change content of one div tag depending on button click. For each button click I would like to inject some html.erb partial.

Why something like this doesn't work:

```
$('#my_div').append '<%= escape_javascript(render("shared/my_partial")) %>'
```

My partial is in the follwoing format: `_my_partial.html.erb`

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you show the controller and view? have you done to write remote true in the button?

Comment: Start by looking in browser console...that syntax will throw errors

Answer (score 0):

Okay, several issues here:

1. You're not binding your `div` replacement to an event?
2. You're using `ERB` code in `front-end` javascript (only works on `ajax` calls)

---

> For each button click I would like to inject some html.erb partial

The two options you have here are to either call the partial through `ajax` (only recommended if you have a dynamic partial) OR preload the partial in a `helper` method or something...

I'll detail both methods.

--

**Ajax**

If your partial has *dynamic* content (IE is populated with a variable or similar), you'll need to pass the request through Ajax.

The reason for this is that Ruby can *only* process `<%= ERB %>` code on the server. Since Javascript is client-side, you have to use ajax to pass an *asynchronous* request to your server, which will render the JS for you.

[Rails UJS](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) introduced the `remote` tag - which removes a lot of the bother from this process:

```
#app/view/controller/your_current_view.html.erb
<%= link_to "your post", your_current_view_path, remote: true %>

#app/controllers/controller.rb
class Controller < ApplicationController
   respond_to :js, :html #-> will need the responders gem after Rails 4

   def your_current_view_path
      ....
   end
end
```

This will allow you to use the following `js.erb` file from the server:

```
#app/views/controller/your_current_view.js.erb
$('#my_div').append('<%=j render "shared/my_partial" %>');
```

This will then allow you to use the partial and any `@instance_variables` you set in the action.

--

**Standalone JS**

If your `partial` is "static" (doesn't require any dynamic data), you'll be able to use the following:

```
#app/views/controller/your_current_view.html.erb
<%= content_tag :div, class: "hidden" do %>
   <%= render "shared/my_partial" %>
<% end %>
```

This will allow you to then use the following JS:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$("a.link").on("click", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   hidden = $(".hidden").html();
   $("div").html(hidden);
});
```